# Android Studio - ACTION_POINTER_UP not working as expected

Tags: android, input

I am making a 2D game.

I have ball #1 and ball #2. I tap and hold ball #1 with finger #1, and then I tap and hold ball #2 with finger #2. Both balls are suspended in the air as long as I keep holding down those 2 fingers.

**When I let go finger #1, why do both balls drop?** I checked System.out.println(), and it registered that whenever I unpressed 1 finger, the second finger also was registered as "ACTION_POINTER_UP", and "ACTION_UP" does not register until I unpress finger #2 (which is too late, ball #2 has already dropped)

The code: i and i2 are itirators withing 2 for loops.

```
if(event.getActionMasked()==event.ACTION_POINTER_UP || event.getActionMasked()==event.ACTION_UP){
     if(arBalls.get(i2).getDragID()==event.getPointerId(i) && arBalls.get(i2).getDrag()){
         arBalls.get(i2).endDrag();
     };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way was to use a correct pointer id

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
    if(arBalls.get(i2).getDragID()==event.getPointerId(event.getActionIndex()) && arBalls.get(i2).getDrag()==true){
        arBalls.get(i2).endDrag();
    }
    break;
}
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
    if(arBalls.get(i2).getDragID() == event.getPointerId(event.getActionIndex()) && arBalls.get(i2).getDrag()==true){
        arBalls.get(i2).endDrag();
    }
    break;
}
```